# Convert variadic template to constexpr

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, constexpr, c++17

I'm wondering if it's possible to convert simple loop that is invoked through a parameter pack into a `constexpr` with simpler code. This example code demonstrates what I'm trying to do

```
struct Student {
    AgeCategory age;
    Income income; 
    bool is_student;
    CreditRating credit_rating;
    bool buys_computer;
};  

auto find_probability(const double x, const double mean, const double stdev) -> double;

typedef std::tuple<double, double> MeanStdDev;
typedef std::vector<MeanStdDev> MeanStdDevVec;


// This code seems verbose to me. Is there a simpler way to express this
// loop which iterates over a vector and parameter pack, possibly 
// using constexpr. C++14/17 idioms are fine.
template<typename Attr>
auto get_probability(const MeanStdDevVec& v, const size_t n, const Student& s, Attr attr) -> double {
    double mean, stdev;
    std::tie(mean, stdev) = v[n];

    return find_probability(static_cast<double>(std::invoke(attr, s)), mean, stdev);
}

template<typename First, typename... Attr>
auto get_probability(const MeanStdDevVec& v, const size_t n, const Student& s, First f, Attr... attr) -> double {
    double mean, stdev;
    std::tie(mean, stdev) = v[n];

    return find_probability(static_cast<double>(std::invoke(f,s)), mean, stdev) * get_probability(v, n + 1, s, attr...);
}

template<typename ...Attr>
auto calculate_class_probability(const std::map<bool, MeanStdDevVec>& summaries, const Student& s, Attr... attributes) {
    for (const auto& i : summaries) {
        get_probability(i.second, 0L, s, attributes...);
    }
}
```

called from

```
 Student s;
 calculate_class_probability(class_summaries, s , &Student::age, &Student::income, &Student::credit_rating, &Student::is_student);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily make the code shorter as a whole, but it does separate out a generic part that you can reuse easily, and IMHO makes the code clearer. The key in this particular case is a function that maps packs into arrays of a certain type:

```
template <class T, class F, class ... Args>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Args)> pack_to_array(F f, Args&& ... args) {
    return {(f(std::forward<Args>(args)))...};
}
```

In your case, this isn't quite enough, as you want to zip it with a vector. So a useful modification of this, would be to make the integer index of the pack element available and pass it to the function:

```
template <class T, class F, class ... Args>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Args)> index_pack_to_array(F f, Args&& ... args) {
    std::size_t i = 0;
    return {(f(i++, std::forward<Args>(args)))...};
}
```

Now, you can use this function like so:

```
template<typename... Attr>
double get_probability(const MeanStdDevVec& v, const Student& s, Attr... attr) {

    assert(v.size() == sizeof...(Attr));
    auto probs = index_pack_to_array<double>(
        [&] (std::size_t i, auto&& a) -> double { 
            return // ... (get probability from v[i], s, and a)
        },
        std::forward<Attr>(attr)...);

    return std::accumulate(probs.begin(), probs.end(), 1.0,
        [] (double p1, double p2) { return p1 * p2; });
}
```

Comment: @Ronnie Thank you! If you feel like it answers your question, mark it accepted (hit the checkmark). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what do you want, but I suppose you can throw away your `getProbability()` and rewrite `calculate_class_probability()` as follows

```
template <typename ... Attr>
auto calculate_class_probability
     (std::map<bool, MeanStdDevVec> const & summaries,
      Student const & s, Attr ... attributes)
 {
   using unusedT = int[];

   for ( const auto & i : summaries )
    {
      double       mean, stdev;
      double       prob {1.0};
      std::size_t  n {0};

      (void)unusedT { (std::tie(mean, stdev) = i.second[n++],
                       prob *= find_probability(static_cast<double>(std::invoke(attributes,s)), mean, stdev),
                       0)... };

      // in prob the calculate value
    }
 }
```

But: no: I don't think it's possible to write this as `constexpr`; the `operator[]` for `std::vector<>` isn't `constexpr`